# Wickham's Advanced R book - Answer to exercise 6.1.2 (Functions)

Tags: r, function

In question 2 Exercise 6.1.2 of Hadely Wickhams -- brilliant -- Advanced R book
the following code is given

```
objs <- mget(ls("package:base"), inherits = TRUE)
funs <- Filter(is.function, objs)
```

In question 2b) the reader is asked to answer:

> How many base functions have no arguments? What's special about those functions?

To get the number of functions that have no arguments I computed the number of arguments per function an selected those that had zero arguments

```
leng <- sapply(funs, function(x) length(formals(x)))
zeroleng <- funs[leng == 0]
```

So there are `lenght(zeroleng) = 222` functions without anyv arguments at all.

My question now is: **What would you say is special about them?**

My first guess was that they are all primitive functions but using `sapply(zeroleng, is.primitive)` shows that while TRUE for most of the functions this is not generally the case.

Greetings Manu

Comment: I think you'll find most of the rest are internal and the remainder are for side effects like the current date and system information.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought. Was just wondering if there is anything I am missing. Just out of interest: do u know if I can somehow test whether a function calls an internal function at some point during execution?

Comment: Roughly, `any(unlist(as.list(body(fn))) %in% c(quote(.Internal)))`, but better to walk the expression tree, see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html#ast-funs.

Answer (score 0):

A good styled answer is here:
https://github.com/peterhurford/adv-r-book-solutions/blob/master/04_functions/01_components/exercise2.r
(some numbers are dated; it is the same as my own one but
is better styled)
I could guess the problem is in knowing the apply()
family of functions. It's advisable to take Chapter 4 
on vocabulary seriously. Many functions are supplied with an easy native help. Some require studying something
intermediate e.g. The Art of R Programming by Matloff.